# How could I create commands using methods from a class in discord.py rewrite?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How could I add commands using a class like this:

```
class BotCreater:
    from discord.ext import commands

    def __init__(self, token, bot_type):
        self.token = token
        self.bot = self.commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
        self.bot.remove_command('help')

    def command(self):
        async def command(ctx):
            await ctx.send("Hello")

    def run(self):
        self.bot.run(self.token)
```

So I could just call `bot_thing = BotCreater(token)`, `bot_thing.command()`, and `bot_thing.run()`, and then it would run the bot with that command.

Comment: Is there a particular problem with the code you have shown?

Comment: The bot runs, but the command is not found.

Comment: Why did you write `async def command` inside `def command`?

Comment: That is how you create commands using discord.py. I know it doesn't do anything, but I wanted to show what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the decorator that registers the coroutine with the bot:

```
def command(self):
    @self.bot.command()
    async def command(ctx):
        await ctx.send("Hello")
```

This is a really weird set-up.  You might look into [cogs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html) instead, which might be a simpler way of doing what you want.