# Error on add a commands decorator to a Discord bot class - discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to create a Discord bot inside a Class but I obtain an error on the following code:

```
from discord import Intents
from discord.ext import commands

class GuessPrompt(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(command_prefix='!', intents=Intents.all())
        self.add_command(self.delete_msg)

    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f"{self.user.display_name} s'est bien connecté au serveur")

    @commands.command(name="delete")
    async def delete_msg(self, ctx, number_of_messages: int = 1):
        messages = await ctx.channel.history(limit=number_of_messages + 1).flatten()

        for each_message in messages:
            await each_message.delete()
```

Error : discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'channel'

It seems not to take into account the context argument (ctx)

An other thing, without `self.add_command(self.delete_msg)` the command is not recognized.

I don't understand why, can you explain me ?

Comment: What message are you sending on Discord? And I don't think you can use the `self` parameter in `delete_msg`, as the class extends `commands.Bot`. Just try removing the `self`. Then, the command should work fine with something like `delete 3`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/63403758/16136190 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63675825/how-could-i-create-commands-using-methods-from-a-class-in-discord-py-rewrite. BTW, I don't think you ever had problems with decorators. You only had problem with a class method's parameters.

Comment: Thank you, I removed the `self`.

But now, the bot didn't take the parameter `number_of_message`.

Comment: What was the message you sent? Try changing the default value (I'm not sure if that's necessary).

Comment: I sent '!delete 3' and it only deleted one message without raising an error. I try with other values but the parameter never seems to be taken into account.

Comment: Sorry, just tested. I guess the class's parameter is clashing with the input one. Why don't you use a normal `@bot.command` decorator without the class? It'd be much easier, and you won't be getting such errors. Do you *have to* use a class? Why?

Comment: I need to use a class because I want to use this code as an API for another script. Thanks anyway for trying.

Comment: You can still try rewriting using `@bot.command`. It'd be easier. Or refer some projects and try fixing.